# I already have a summer internship but got another offer from a family friend. Is there a way to ask if I can intern with him next summer?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, internship

My current internship is the best learning experience and is offering me a part-time job through school, next year. 
But this family friend has a really good internship with a big company. I want to do it next summer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about the workplace, it is about the etiquette of communications with a family friend.

Comment: Phone, email or even postal mail are three options that come to mind

Comment: @MarvMills - I have to disagree that this is off-topic. The family friend aspect is just extraneous information. He has an internship and has been offered another desirable one. What should he do? That's quite a relevant  dilemma for a student entering the workplace.

Comment: The only reason I mentioned it's a family friend is that he will remember me if I apply next summer. This is a useful question regarding how to deal with multiple job offers.

Comment: This really comes down to a question about which job to take then.  And that is explicitly off topic.  The bottom line for you is which internship will help your career more in the end.  Take that one.

Comment: Distil all this down and the actual question being asked is "I have received a second offer. Is there a way to ask them if I can take up the second offer next year" - And the answer is, as Kilisi alludes, "Yes, ask them using a communications medium". As worded, this is not a Workplace question.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about business communication, even with a family friend, is that clarity can be a good thing.

Thank the friend for the offer and explain that you've already accepted a different internship.  Since you have accepted it, you won't go back on that offer.  And then ask if there is any chance that the internship might be available next summer as well.

In other words, just say what you want to say.

Comment: Exactly! You've made a commitment and you need to stick with it. More than experience is on the line. Your word and reputation are as well.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you both, and I like the wording.